# Need to return value from scheduled method in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I am writing scheduler in my web application for notification purpose, the task of my scheduler is simple, It will hit the third party centralised database and look for the availability of data, if data is available then it returns true otherwise false.

But I am stuck here, I want to show the notification on based on the result (true/false)returning by my scheduler, but I am not able to think, how do I implement the same? I thought of bind the variable in session, but because it is time even so session is not possible here.

Suppose scheduler returning true, now I want this value inside my JSP page(Dashboard page) where I can able to show the message that "Data is available" in user's dashboard. I need this value to check condition

```
if(true)
"data is available"
else
no notification
```

Please see my code and suggest me.

```
package com.awzpact.uam.scheduler;

import com.awzpact.prayas.dao.HRMSPickSalaryDataDAO;
import com.awzpact.uam.domain.SalaryDetailReport;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class PayrollDataNotificationScheduler {

    private static  boolean AVAIL_STATUS = false;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PayrollDataNotificationScheduler.class);

    public boolean checkDataAvailability() {

        try {
            List<SalaryDetailReport> list = salaryDataDAO.findAll();
            if (list.size() > 0) {
                AVAIL_STATUS = true;
                return AVAIL_STATUS;
            }

            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.info("Data is not available for migrate");
            return false;
        }
    }
    @Autowired
    HRMSPickSalaryDataDAO salaryDataDAO;
}
```

Comment: Why won't you use some kind of AJAX call? You can use scheduler to set up some global variable or a field in the DB periodically and then ask for it from frontend. Or maybe you can use sockets if you want it to be more of "real-time"?

Comment: ok, how do I implement socket here, can you demonstrate please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run your scheduled task periodically if there's some data retrieved - you save it to your DB.

```
// in your scheduled @Component
@Autowired
private SomeDataDAO someDataDAO;

@Scheduled(cron = "...")
public void fetchThirdPartyData() {

    SomeData thirdPartyData = getThirdPartyData();
    someDataDAO.save(thirdPartyData);
}

private SomeData getThirdPartyData() {
    // calling their API...
}
```

Then you create a controller which is going to get the data from db (if exists, notice the `Optional` interface - you can use this in your `DAO` method)

```
// a rest controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/someData")
public class SomeController {

    @Autowired
    private SomeDataDAO someDataDAO;

    @GetMapping
    public SomeData getSomeData() {
        return someDataDao.getSomeData().orElse(null);
    }

}
```

Now, in your fronted you do some AJAX call, depending on what you're using there and then you can do your check and print the message.

Comment: thank you so much for your kind help, I will going to implement the same

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling means that you want to make some actions on the schedule basis. 
Waiting for response looks more like request/response communication between client and server.
To check that data is available - it's better to use simple method invocation via REST Controller and don't use a scheduler at all.

Comment: I want to schedule this method for 25,26 and 27th of every month